# math.h Included by Default in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, include

I have a multi-platform project, running on Windows, Linux and iOS right now, but I have stumbled upon a undesirable problem with Objective-C.

I have, unfortunately, chose the name `exp` for one of my types (expressions, pretty reasonable given the number of occurrences in my code), but Objective-C somehow includes the `math.h` header by default, creating a name-clash.

I tried to comment out everything in the .pch (the prefix file included by default before every source file), and `exp` is still flagged as redefinition.

Does anybody know how to **not** include math.h in a source file inside Objective-C project?

Comment: Call your type `Expr` and stop worrying about math.h

Comment: Agree with @JimBalter (use Expression).  Furthermore, I was coding back when compilers had symbol name length limitations, and we had to worry about name clashes because of limited symbol name length.  Now, however, there is no excuse at all for using small parts of a word as a symbol.  So, I would never consider "exp" a reasonable type for an expression.  Valid alternatives, depending on coding style, would be: expression, expression_t, Expression, but probably then only within namespaces.  Without a namespace, they should all be prefixed with some reasonable prefix: e.g., XIXIXAO_Expression.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, but I know that I can (and do) simply rename the type. The reason I am interested in a work-around is that we have a really nice naming convention (there are other types and function names bound to this `exp`) and this seems like a breach of Objective-C's promise to compile C99 code straightforwardly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C does not have a formal specification, but it inherits features from C. In C, programs should not use identifiers from the standard headers, even if they do not include those headers. So, you should not use “exp” for your own identifiers.

If you insist upon using “exp”, you might be able to work around the issue with a preprocessor statement:

```
#define exp MyExp
```

This will allow you to write “exp” in your source code as if it were one of your identifiers. Since the preprocessor will change it to “MyExp”, the compiler will see “MyExp” as the identifier and will not complain.

This will cause a number of problems, such as the identifier showing up as “MyExp” in object code information and in debugging tools and causing inability to use exp from math.h in the future.

Comment: For now, this is the best workaround, including this directive in the file where `exp` is declared let's me keep my code as it works on other platforms.

Comment: Then you might consider using a name that explains what is going on, such as `#define exp ThisIs_exp_InTheSourceCodeButRenamedByPreprocessorDefineToWorkAroundConflictWithReservedSymbol`, so that anybody who sees it while debugging understands what it is.